# After logging out, the session is not finished and you are logged in again

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logout

I have problem with logout my page.

After you log out, I don't know why you log in again. The cookie is deleted and a new cookie is created.

Spring Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Qualifier("myUserDetailsService")
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.simpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler = simpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/addUser", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }





}
```

Code:

https://github.com/lakomika/Shop

Can you see why this is happening?

Comment: basic authentication won't log out. Credentials are send with every request by the browser and you will login automatically again.

Comment: What do you recommend to do with logging out in Angular?

Comment: @lakomika, where do you save your  basic auth token in your angular application? in window localStorage or session storage?

Comment: Remove the token in angular. However it might still be send with your browser.